# Defining a generic function and implementing specialised methods

Tags: functions, cl-lib

Emacs provides support for polymorphism, supporting "generic functions", like in CLOS.
According to Emacs manual:

> A generic function specifies an abstract operation, by defining its
>   name and list of arguments, but (usually) no implementation.  The actual
>   implementation for several specific classes of arguments is provided by
>   "methods", which should be defined separately [...]
>   by “specializing” the arguments defined by the generic function.

Unfortunately the manual does not give practical examples of a methods implementation once a generic function is defined. 
Can you give such an example, implementing the standard OO paradigms through `cl-defgeneric`/`cl-defmethod`?

Comment: The elisp manual has a decent amount to say about them. `C-h i g (elisp) Generic Functions`. Always check the manual.

Comment: You could look at Common Lisp docs (such as the hyperspec).

Comment: If you do not find the doc to be as helpful as you think it should be please consider reporting that as a doc bug/suggestion: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: In general, I think the doc for CL stuff in Emacs is pretty poor. Typically, you need to consult the Common  Lisp doc, and then sometimes try to figure out how the Emacs-Lisp implementation might differ.

Comment: Try looking in the `cl` manual, as well. In principle, that is where I would *expect* `cl` stuff to be documented. But that manual is pretty skimpy...

Comment: @Drew: Not even mentioned in [emacs/manual/cl.html#Function-Index](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/cl.html#Function-Index). I will consider the doc suggestion

Comment: @phils: I did not find examples [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/elisp.html#Generic-Functions), only a short abstract comparison among OO languages.

Comment: No examples (my comment wasn't intended as an *answer*); but you said you were "unable to find documentation" apart from the docstrings, and that manual page contains rather more information than the docstrings. Reminding you that the manual is a thing that exists seemed fairly useful.

Comment: Can you edit the post to make the question more discrete and less open-ended?  The format of this site does not really lend itself to open-ended tutorials very well.

Comment: @Dan: I tried to narrow and focus the scope by linking the question to the manual reference to Generic Functions (strongly advocated by phils too).

Answer (score 4):

An attempt...

```
(require 'cl-generic)

;; Checking accounts can have a negative balance
;; Savings accounts can't
(cl-defstruct checking-account balance)
(cl-defstruct savings-account balance)

;; A generic `withdraw' method
(cl-defgeneric withdraw (account amount)    
  (:documentation "Withdraw AMOUNT from ACCOUNT balance.
Give an error for savings accounts where balance < AMOUNT"))

;; Implementation of `withdraw' for checking accounts
(cl-defmethod withdraw ((account checking-account) amount)
  (cl-decf (checking-account-balance account) amount))

;; Implementation of `withdraw' for savings accounts
(cl-defmethod withdraw ((account savings-account) amount)
  (when (< (savings-account-balance account) amount)
    (error "Account overdrawn."))
  (cl-decf (savings-account-balance account) amount))

;; Account instantiations, i.e. creation of account objects  
(setq x (make-checking-account :balance 50))
(setq y (make-savings-account :balance 50))

;; Withdraw amounts from accounts 
(withdraw x 60) ; => - 10
(withdraw y 60) ; => (error "Account overdrawn.")
```

See [gigamonkeys.com](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/object-reorientation-generic-functions.html) for Common Lisp.

Comment: You might want to amend or extend this example to improve readability or effectiveness.